# XAML - How to create a User Control that add a Path Object to the .Xaml

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, design-time

**Preamble:** I have to design components that work with Visual Studio WPF Designer to create custom applications. For example a Line User Control.

**Scenario**

In Blend 2012, if you draw a line on the Designer Surface, the editor creates something like

```
<Path Data="M5.5,5.5 L502.5,308.5" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="304" Margin="5.5,5.5,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="498"/>
```

in the .xaml behind code at Design Time, even if you can expect something like

```
<BlendLineControl  ... />
```

like every noraml WPF User Control.

**The Problem**

I need to create a similar control in Visual Studio with which the user can draw a line on the Designer Surface and when the draw ends the control adds a `Path` to the .xaml behind, instead of

```
<myControls:myLineControl ... />
```

Is there a way to achieve this result?

Comment: That's *not* how WPF works. Please explain what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: `Designer surface` - forget that. No one cares about the designer in WPF.

Comment: Hi guys. Thank you for you replies. @Sheridan If you open Blend 2012 and draw a line, you will notice that the something like <Path Data="... will appear on the xaml part of your code. I need to do something similar.

Comment: @HighCore I know, but I HAVE TO design components that work with VS WPF Designer to create custom applications.

Answer (score 1):

@Riccardo, your question description is very poor and that is why you still haven't received any proper answers, even after 17 hours. This is not a criticism, but advice instead. If you carefully think about what you want and how best to put it into words *before* you ask your question, you will probably get better and quicker answers.

Only after reading your comments, was I able to guess what you *actually* wanted, as that was not at all clear from your question. In your comment, you said

> I HAVE TO design components that work with VS WPF Designer to create custom applications

I have no idea why you wouldn't put crucial information like that into your question, but now that I know that, I can suggest a possible solution for you. Of course, that's still not a very clear description, so this might not be what you're after, but I think that you are looking for some way to extend the functionality of the Visual Studio WPF Designer.

If that is the case, then please see the [WPF Designer Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546938%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) pages on MSDN. They will show you how to add custom editors, or `Adorner`s into the Visual Studio WPF Designer and describe how to implement custom design-time logic, among other things.

If this is not what you are after, then I have no clue what you do want and suggest that you seriously improve the clarity of your question.

Comment: Thank you again, but I don't agree with you when you say that the description is very poor. In my question I wrote that: "I need to create a UserControl that adds something like <code> to the Xaml at Design Time". Easy to understand, I suppose. IMHO There is no need to explain why I have to do such an uncommon thing.
Anyway...I'm reading and reading all the articles from that page, but I still haven't found what I am looking for. 
Did you try to draw a line in Blend and see the behaviour I mentioned before?

Comment: *I don't agree with you when you say that the description is very poor*... that's just crazy. I'm trying to help you and telling you that I can't because I can't understand what you actually want and you want to ignore that fact. *IMHO There is no need to explain why I have to do such an uncommon thing.* The reason is that it helps those trying to help you, but please continue with your poor quality questions if you don't want any further help on this website. My comments were supposed to be helpful advice to help get your questions answered... it's totally up to you if you act on them or not.

Comment: Hey, fly down Sherry. Everyone is free to say what he wants. You have your ideas, I have my ideas. Anyway I rearranged my question (same words in a different order) but I still don't know if you tried the example in Blend just to really understand the problem I exposed here.

Comment: *Hey, fly down Sherry*... really? All I can say is that I tried to help you and good luck with finding your answer.

Answer (score -3):

hello you should register a dependency property. and then implement how to interpret the value that would be passed to you

as an example, i have this small user control

```
<UserControl x:Class="Gnl.FxWinModule.ViewViewModel.LegView">
    <Grid>
        <dxlc:LayoutGroup x:Name="LegLayoutGroup" 
                          View="GroupBox"                                       
                          Grid.Column="0>
        </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
    </Grid>
</UserControl> and i would like to put it in a parentWindow and i want my layout group to have a different header name. so i declare a dependency property like this 

public static readonly DependencyProperty LegNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LegName", typeof(string), typeof(LegView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, OnLegNameChanged));

 public string LegName
 {
    get { return (string)GetValue(LegNameProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LegNameProperty, value); }
 }

 private static void OnLegNameChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    var legControl = (LegView)sender;
    legControl.LegLayoutGroup.Header = (string)e.NewValue;
 } 

 public string GetViewName()
 {
    return string.Empty;
 }
```

i'm now able to declare the following in my parent windows <`VM:LegView Grid.Column="0" LegName="Buy Leg"/>` hope it helps you

Comment: You haven't understood the requirements, or perhaps you're answering another question?

Comment: This reply is not relevant to the question.